# Documentation about Roles

Tags: perl, interface, oop, roles, behavior

some time ago I found an article ([Roles: Composable Units of Object Behavior](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/08/roles_composable_units_of_obje.html)) describing the pros of using Roles versus Interfaces or other ways of dealing with behavior requirements. Does any of you knows where I can find more literature about that, or knows more about Roles?

I know that that's almost a research topic, but maybe someone (maybe some Perl programmer) has tried something with it (Moose?).

Note: the reason for adding tag "perl" is that maybe Perl programmers are more likely to give an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Moose based examples, you should check [this](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Roles/Recipe1.pod) and [that](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Roles/Recipe2.pod) example and [this](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Moose/lib/Moose/Spec/Role.pod) specification.

ETA: For the theoretical aspects, see [this](http://www.iam.unibe.ch/~scg/Research/Traits/) page

Comment: I know, but I also wanted to learn more about the Roles base theory, not only in Perl ...

Comment: Roles are an implementation of Traits, though there are a couple of small differences. Traits are a bit more 'pure'